# SSH ChrootDirectory on Mac OS X Lion (not Server edition)

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

I'm trying to setup a remote-only user account on my MacBook Pro that is chrooted to `/chroot/tmux`. I've followed the steps outlined here (http://thefragens.com/blog/2011/12/chrootd-sftp-on-mac-os-x-server/), but when I try to login in with (on my local network):

```
ssh tmux@10.0.1.140
```

... I get an immediate connection closed:

```
❯ ssh tmux@10.0.1.140                                                                                                        
Password:
Connection to 10.0.1.140 closed by remote host.
Connection to 10.0.1.140 closed.
```

Removing this line in `/etc/sshd_config` allows me to login fine, but my `tmux` user is no longer chrooted:

```
Match User tmux
  # ...
  ChrootDirectory /chroot/tmux # removing this allows me to login
```

What do I have to do to get this to work?

---

This is what I get after the password prompt when I try to login from the client with `ssh -vv tmux@10.0.1.140`:

```
debug2: input_userauth_info_req 
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 0 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive). 
Authenticated to 10.0.1.140 ([10.0.1.140]:22). 
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session] 
debug2: channel 0: send open 
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com 
debug1: Entering interactive session. 
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1 
Connection to 10.0.1.140 closed by remote host.
Connection to 10.0.1.140 closed.
Transferred: sent 1872, received 1880 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 100689.1, received 101119.4
debug1: Exit status -1
```

---

Encouragingly, Mac's Console reports this:

```
6/15/12 9:57:42.679 AM sshd: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/chroot/tmux"
```

My current directory permissions:

```
~ ❯ ls -al /chroot/tmux                                                                                                                      
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  7 tmux  wheel  238 Jun 14 11:18 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Jun 14 10:34 ..
```

Comment: Those instructions you are looking at are for an SFTP connection only, but you appear to be trying to connect with SSH.  Are you expecting to get a chroot shell?

Comment: Yeah, want a chrooted shell. I couldn't find any article detailing how to get that, and the SFTP one seemed to closest fit.

Comment: Can you try adding "-vv" to your ssh login session on the client? Also check Console on the Mac to see what the SSH server says about it.

Comment: @JamesHannah Console app seems to give me the cause here, which seems to be a permissions issue. Should I have them set to something other than what was outlined in the article mentioned in my post?

Comment: @neezer the SSH manpage is very specific about this: "All components of the pathname [provided to ChrootDirectory] must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the ownership and permissions on the directory /chroot/tmux.

The SSHD manpage states:

> **ChrootDirectory**
>
> ```
>          Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after
>          authentication.  All components of the pathname must be root-
>          owned directories that are not writable by any other user or
>          group.  After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory
>          to the user's home directory.
> ```

I believe the specific path given to ChrootDirectory (in your case /home/tmux) must be root:root and at most 755 permissions, it looks like your directory is owned by 'tmux'.

Also note however, the ChrootDirectory command works best with SFTP, which doesn't require a specific shell, if you're trying to run interactive SSH command-line sessions (and a shell) from this directory, you'll need to add some files to the chroot first, as described in the sshd_config manpage:

> The **ChrootDirectory** must contain the necessary files and directo-ries to support the user's session.  For an interactive session this requires at least a shell, typically sh(1), and basic /dev nodes such as null(4), zero(4), stdin(4), stdout(4), stderr(4),    arandom(4) and tty(4) devices.  For file transfer sessions using ``sftp'', no additional configuration of the environment is nec-essary if the in-process sftp server is used, though sessions which use logging do require /dev/log inside the chroot directory (see sftp-server(8) for details).

Comment: Yeah, I was playing with this the other day. What I'm ultimately after is to create an SSH bridge from some other computer on my network through my computer to a Vagrant VM hosted on my computer. What I've done up until now is provided shell access into my machine so they can then run SSH from within that into Vagrant. (so a SFTP setup doesn't really solve my issue). I've tried setting up the files and directories, but I keep getting errors about ttys005... so that's where I'm at currently. Any thoughts?

Comment: So you're just trying to do a sort of port forward? SSH has options for that if you are, and you can configure it so that port forwarding's the only thing that can be done.